# Is there a way this query can be optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Below is my query, and is there a way to optimize my query so that the cost would be reduced

**FYI : There's already index created on JTASK.JOBHANDLE and JLIST.HANDLE**

```
SELECT JLIST.*, 
       JTASK.jtstatus   LATESTTASKSTATUS, 
       JTASK.jtruncount JOBRUNCOUNT, 
       JTASK.objecthandle 
FROM   esm_n_joblist JLIST 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT JT1.jobhandle, 
                               JT1.taskstatus   JTSTATUS, 
                               JT2.rc           JTRUNCOUNT, 
                               JT1.objecthandle objecthandle 
                        FROM   esm_n_jobtasklist JT1, 
                               (SELECT Count(DISTINCT runid) RC, 
                                       jobhandle             JH, 
                                       Max (starttime)       MAXT 
                                FROM   esm_n_jobtasklist 
                                GROUP  BY jobhandle) JT2 
                        WHERE  JT1.jobhandle = JT2.jh 
                               AND JT2.maxt = JT1.starttime) JTASK 
                    ON JLIST.handle = JTASK.jobhandle;
```

Below is the execution plan of the query

[image]

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: did you try creating a composite index with starttime ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Yes, I created a unique composite index on Jobhandle and Start time, but it was of no use

Comment: That's odd. An index on (jobhandle, start time) seems like it would be useful (you would delete the existing jobhandle index)

Comment: Note that as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN

Comment: That execution plan did not come from MySQL; where did it come from?  Do you have the correct tag?

Comment: If you don't need `LEFT`, removing it may speed up the query.

Answer (score 1):

The index below has a good chance of speeding up your query:

```
create index ix_jtl1 on esm_n_jobtasklist (jobhandle, starttime, runid);
```

Please provide the execution plan BEFORE and AFTER you added this index.